# How to put sign on marked places in document pages

Tags: docusignapi

Based on docusignapi functionality need to put sign on marked places in document pages,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the auto-place feature (also called anchor-tagging) you can specify the location of your tabs based on content or "markers" contained within your documents.

See Documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs#tab-positioning).

Api Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/#anchoring-tabs)